# UILabel text color changes when text is changed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, nib, uicolor

The UILabel is created in Interface builder. It is part of a UITableViewCell. Its color is set to red in Interface Builder.

I create the cells here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"notationcell";
    NotationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.notation = [self.notations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIColor *before = cell.symbolLabel.textColor;
    cell.symbolLabel.text = @"new text";
    UIColor *after = cell.symbolLabel.textColor;

    return cell;
}
```

Before is red, as intended. But after changing the text the after color becomes UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1, and the text becomes black. I am using AutoLayout.

Why does changing the text imply the change of its color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. I created a category:

```
@implementation UILabel (KeepAttributes)

- (void)setTextWithKeepingAttributes:(NSString *)text{

    NSDictionary *attributes = [(NSAttributedString *)self.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL];
    self.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];

}

@end
```

Then used this method to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text color to be permanently red try setting the Label's text color in the delegate method itself rather than from XIB:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"notationcell";
    NotationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.notation = [self.notations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.symbolLabel.text = @"new text";
    cell.symbolLabel.textColor = [UIColor RedColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a solution, but I'd like these things set, and shown correctly in Interface Builder, because I have to work with people who need to see the layouts. There are lot of other attributes besides color, which should be kept the way they are set in IB.